# How to identify slow connection with IPv6

Tags: ipv6, hetzner

I'm a  [Hetzner](https://www.hetzner.de/en/) customer, and I have twice had the same problem when using their standard Ubuntu 16 LTS image on a new server. When I try to download packages it is incredibly slow and will often sit waiting for 10s on minutes on a single package.

I have "solved" this problem by forcing IPv4, but I don't understand where the problem is. So far Hetzner support have not been able to solve this issue.

```
echo 'Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4
```

Is this an issue on my own server or else somewhere in the Hetzner network infrastructure?

Requests to Hetzner mirrors are OK, but external servers are taking an extremely long time to complete, eg: it is hanging on requests to ubuntu.com

`Get:14 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt xenial-pgdg/main amd64 Packages [58.8
kB]Get:15 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt xenial-pgdg/main i386 Packages [58.6
kB]0% [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1560:8001::14)]`

Comment: do you checked this with traceroute6 or mtr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my case, since I built the server from a Cloud-ISO installation, the IPV6 was set with a different IP from my real one.

So I just had to change the wrong one with mine. 
Here all details from Hetzner's wiki: https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Cloud_ISO_Installation_Gateway/en

Comment: Can you explain how having a different (presumaly wrong) IPv6 address configured would produce the symptoms described in the question?

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm this probably has something to do with their network infrastructure.

I couldn't even make proper requests to the hetzner mirrors with IPv6 without it crawling or completely not working.

Forcing IPv4 as you have listed seems to have "fixed" it for me as well.